# A path concatenated with os.path.join in a RHEL environment is using two different separators

Tags: python, path, rhel

I have some code that needs to work cross-platform and calls a subprocess of conda.exe. Prior to calling the subprocess, I create the path to conda.exe using the following code (and this path is then used to call conda.exe in the subprocess later on):

```
install_dir = os.path.normpath(arcpy.GetInstallInfo()["InstallDir"])
conda = os.path.join(install_dir,
                             "bin",
                             "Python",
                             "Scripts",
                             "conda.exe")
```

This works perfectly fine on Windows and Ubuntu, but on RHEL the path returned uses two different separators, example below (ellipsis is not part of path):

```
z:\\...\\arcgis\\server\\framework\\runtime\\arcgis\\/bin/Python/Scripts/conda.exe
```

Needless to say, when I try to call conda in the subprocess, I get a "No such file or directory" error.

Any idea why the path is being put together using two different separators when running in RHEL? So far I have not been able to come up with a solution that works, thank you for any help that points me in the right direction!

Comment: If you have a program called `conda.exe` you are on Windows, not Red Hat.

Answer (score 1):

You can either switch to using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) for an object-oriented approach to filesystems, or build your string using [os.sep](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.sep) to avoid issues with cross-platform differences.

Using pathlib:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> pro_install_dir = Path("z:\\...\\arcgis\\server\\framework\\runtime\\arcgis\\")
>>> conda = pro_install_dir / "bin" / "Python" / "Scripts"/ "conda.exe"
>>> conda
WindowsPath('z:/.../arcgis/server/framework/runtime/arcgis/bin/Python/Scripts/conda.exe')
```

Comment: Thank you! I am trying out the pathlib route, will post back next week if it succeeded/failed again.

Comment: Part of the problem seems to be that z:/ will not exist in Linux, also everything is lower cased in the path, which Linux does not accept. The workaround will be dealing with this.